# MPAndroidChart BarChart disable right legends

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to remove right legends from `BarChart`.

This is my code.

```
    mChart = (BarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(2);

    ValueFormatter custom = new MyValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(8);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);

    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
    l.setForm(LegendForm.SQUARE);
    l.setFormSize(9f);
    l.setTextSize(11f);
    l.setXEntrySpace(4f);

    mChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add this line

```
rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
```

To hide **only the labels**.

For **hiding the whole right axis**, call:

```
rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple one liner:

```
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using **Kotlin** lang:

```
chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
```

*Hope it helps!*